# How to install framework 3.5 to windows server 2012?

Tags: windows, server

I have a windows VPS with windows server 2012. I need to install framework 3.5
I tried the adding roles step but it keeps failing. See screenshot

https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/GNJuMDiXHNj2RcmUFIRqZajc8wL8hZ9A-bo6Dlxdm7ge9QPqU8Lb65Ce56QrIilTIPpmQyf23U2vcMetw_of=w1340-h1335

Please kindly help me on how to successfully install it. I tried several ways that i found on google but it doesnt work.

Comment: You mean .net framework? The screenshot doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3002547

Turn on the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 feature before you install security update 2966827 or 2966828. For more information about how to turn Windows features on or off, go to the following Microsoft webpage: Turn Windows features on or off. You can also use Deployment Image Servicing and Management (DISM) or any supported managed update system to add the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 feature. For more information about how to deploy the .NET Framework 3.5 by using DISM, go to the following Microsoft webpage: Deploy .NET Framework 3.5 by using Deployment Image Servicing and Management (DISM)
If security update 2966827 or 2966828 has already been installed on the system, temporarily uninstall the update, enable .NET Framework 3.5, and then reinstall the security update.
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to update with latest patches (optionals also) the Operating System.

Then I added the W2012 dvd to disk D

And finally run the command:

```
dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /all /Source:D:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess
```

Answer (score 0):

If your server has network, PowerShell is the best way to install .net framework 3.5.

Copy the whole commands, and paste into PowerShell.

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU' -Name UseWUServer -Value 0
Restart-Service -Name wuauserv
Install-WindowsFeature Net-Framework-Core
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU' -Name UseWUServer -Value 1
Restart-Service -Name wuauserv
```